# creting file/directory in c#

Tags: c#, file, directory

I have some folders/files in several drive like

```
C:\New Folder
C:\a.txt
D:\New Folder\New Folder
D:\New Folder\a.txt
```

Now i want to create a directory tree in c drive that will look like

```
C:\mytempFolder\driveC\New Folder
C:\mytempFolder\driveC\a.txt
C:\mytempFolder\driveD\New Folder\New Folder
C:\mytempFolder\driveD\New Folder\a.txt
```

Is there any shortcut way to implement this in c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Directory.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to create the directories:

```
Directory.Create("c:\mytempFolder\driveC\New Folder");
```

and to create the files, you'll have to write a text file to that location, like so:

```
File.Create("D:\New Folder\a.txt").Close;
```

(It returns a FileSream, so remember to close this afterwards or you will lock the file)

**EDIT:**

Ok I see what you mean. It that case you need to do something like this:

[Loop all files in directory and its sub directories](http://www.snippetit.com/2009/02/c-loop-all-files-in-directory-and-its-sub-directories/)

and when you come across a file or folder, you'll then need to create it in your target folder (i.e. c:\mytempFolder) using the above commands. To get the drive you can simply get the first character in the path string (assuming it will always have a drive letter).

Here's a simple way of doing that but you may need to tweak it to account of filepath inconsistencies:

```
string targetPath = @"C:\mytempFolder\";
string path = @"D:\New Folder\a.txt";
char driveLetter = path[0];
string filePath = path.SubString(3);
string newFilePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, Path.Combine(String.Format("drive{0}", driveLetter.ToString()), filePath));
```

Comment: I don't directly know the name of New Folder.This is full path of a directory.I have to extract this without drive letter along with :\.I did it programaticaly using string operation.So i asked a way to get path without drive so i can directly use "c:\mytempfolder\driveC\"+fullpathWithoutDrive

Comment: well, what you said i have done already.taking the first character of path(C/d)then creating directory under mytempfolder like drive(c\d) and so on.I just wanted to know is there any operation i could do that would give me the relative path without drive and then directly create the required file/folder by appending with mytempfodler/drive(c/d)

Comment: Ok you didn't mention that, but long story short no there's not. You'll have to write something to do that for you. Should be straight forward enough though

Answer (score 3):

```
   if(System.IO.Directory.Exists("c://gg"))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\gg//");
            System.IO.File.Create("C:\\gg//file.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ALREADY FOLDER EXIST");
        }
```

Comment: But what if textbox1 contains full file name like c:\new Folder\a.txt

Comment: then -- System.IO.File.Create("textbox1.text"); remove "C:\\gg//";

Comment: I don't know whether i make you understand the problem or not.Think you got the list in your program then you have to create the tree structure from your program